# How to block tcp-reset with iptables to combat DDoS attacks?

Tags: iptables, ddos

I have someone flooding me with random packets on random ports that are closed.

My server is responding to this with tcp-reset packets I think which is chewing up the outbound bandwidth too.

How do I use iptables to block tcp-reset packets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `DROP` target is the one you want.

If you only have the single box and no other machines in your network are making connections to it, you could get away with blocking all `RESET` packets.

```
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -j DROP
```

*See [packet-filtering-HOWTO-7](https://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/packet-filtering-HOWTO-7.html) for details*

This is not very polite to legitimate connections if you happen to be down and it can cause unneeded timeouts in established connections that need to use a `RESET` packet.  It's not a great idea permanently but if it allows you to handle a DDoS then it should be OK temporarily.

If your normal usage of this box relies on `RESET` packets working for normal users and you want to only block the `RESET` packets for the attacker, you will want to identify the malicious packets so we can block only those.

Are these packets truly random or is there something they all have in common?

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -j LOG
```

If you add a `LOG` line to the end of your iptables config, you can use that log to analyse the inbound packets to see if there's a pattern.  A scatter plot of the source and destination port numbers will probably be useful.  Plotting the IP addresses on an IP-space map could possibly help to identify malicious and benign ranges although I suspect this is less likely to produce useful results.  Simply counting the number of attacking IP addresses will be useful.  If it's a small enough number, you can simply add them all to the iptables config.

Even if you don't find a pattern, since there is definitely a pattern based on "too many reset packets" you can create a fail2ban rule that will add a `DROP` rule for any IP address that causes more than x `RESET` packets in y seconds.

Comment: Do I really need the reset packet? It doesn't sound very useful.

Comment: The IPs are spoofed, fail2ban won't do anything.

Comment: It won't matter if they're spoofed packets.  As long as they're consistent, fail2ban can identify them and prevent sending `RESET` packets in response to them.  How do you know they're spoofed?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind when adding a LOG rule to `iptables`, is that he logs may grow really fast if you are under attack receiving 1 million plus hits an hour. That can fill up your allotted hard drive space in no time.

Comment: TCP RST is useful in load-balancing setups, when a non-ready backend responds with a RST, allowing the load-balancer to quickly switch to another instance. Without a RST, waiting until a timeout is the only alternative. See [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/103283/56233) for more reasons for why you'd want to allow TCP RST.

Answer (score 0):

You can '-j DROP' instead of '-j REJECT --with-tcp-reset'.

Comment: How do I do this without blocking every port?

Comment: Edit the corresponding rules accordingly. Paste full conf if you need further details.

Comment: This is a great answer... for a different question. Note that tcp reset is sent automatically by the OS for any closed port. There is no "-j REJECT" involved.